# How can I get post data from my db - multiple fetch

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php 
if ($username = $_GET['username']) 
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='$username'";
   $q = $db->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute();

   while($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
      echo "$username<br/>";
   }
}
?>
```

Hello everybody. I wanna if username for ex Baran just fetch baran's posts. I have these code and I am getting usernames but when I try the get post date from posts table it does not work. What am I suppose to do.

Comment: hoe are you trying to get the date, can you please show your code

Comment: my codes are just a little bit long and it has some functions files. I think the problem somewhere in functions files. I just wanna learn something different. Maybe I am missing somewhere :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its a typo

```
if ($username = $_GET['username']) {// assingment
```

change to:

```
if ($username == $_GET['username']) {//equal
```

use [preparedStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to avoid sql injection:

```
<?php 
if ($username == $_GET['username']) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = :user ";
   $q = $db->prepare($sql);
   $q->bindValue(':user', $username);
   $q->execute();
   while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['username'] .'<br/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: this one is works perfectly but I wanna get another variable from posts table which name is POST. My purpose is if username for ex Baran fetch all baran's post not username. I hope u can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something similar? change `if ($username == $_GET['username']) {`

```
while($row = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  echo $row['username'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of `$q->fetch` to some variable. See [fetch() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

In your example you just echo the value used as input.

Answer (score 0):

inside if you should always be using ==

```
eg:if($i ==1)
{
something here
}
else
{
something else
}
```